# Why did I get the Snaphat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

I just got the Snaphat today but I haven't answered recently, and my two recent answers don't meet the criteria. The earlier one of the two just got an accept a few hours ago (the criteria says must be within 30 minutes of the time when question was asked) and I posted it on December 22nd. The later one of the two only has +2 with no accept. How did I get the hat on Stack Overflow?

Comment: They're counting in [Microsoft minutes](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Microsoft%20minute)...

Comment: @macro https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040106-00/?p=41193

Answer (score 1):

There are [known issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288779/295232) with the Snaphat. The 30 minute criterium seems not to be checked in every case; often, it's enough to be the first answerer.